# Converting basic angles over each axis of a 3d rotation to euler angles or axis angles or quartenion

Tags: 3d, rotations

For a 3d rotation, if I know that I want to rotate e.g. around X axis with 15 degrees, around Y axis with 226 degrees and around Z axis with 0 degrees: how to calculate Euler angles from this ? I need the conversion in order to get 3x3 rotation matrix.
actually what I want is: 
https://www.andre-gaschler.com/rotationconverter/
there you can enter in "Axis with angle magnitude" the angles and you get the Euler angles. What formula to use to get the same result?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [Rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle) has a section "Rotation matrix from axis and angle". Construct the three matrices, $R_1$ being the first rotation, $R_2$ the second rotation, and $R_3$ the third. The combined rotation is then obtained via [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Definition): $R = R_3 R_2 R_1$. (The order of the rotation matrices is latest left, oldest right, when combining them via matrix-matrix multiplication.)

Comment: "For some applications, it is helpful to be able to make a rotation with a given axis. Given a unit vector u = (ux,uy,uz), the matrix for a rotation by an angle of θ about an axis in the direction of u is" 
I have 3 values which are angles, not a unit vector and an angle of rotation around it. how to convert my angles to axis angles or quartenion?

Comment: If you want to rotate around the $x$ axis, then your unit vector us $(1, 0, 0)$. If around the $y$ axis, $(0, 1, 0)$. If around the $z$ axis, $(0, 0, 1)$. Each rotation gives you a single matrix (or quaternion). Multiply them to get the combined rotation.

Comment: As I have often remarked before, Euler angles are evil, because there are several different incompatible ways they can be defined: the order of the axes is important, and is often forgotten, so results can be hard to duplicate.

Comment: @Nominal Animal:
for some reason is not working.
I did the following, I tried to rotate -30 degrees around X axis, 220 degrees around Y axis and 60 degrees around Z axis.
so I created Mx, My, Mz rotation matrices(exactly like specified in wikipedia)
created M = Mx x My x Mz (matrix multiplication) -> M does not contain correct values. compared using https://www.andre-gaschler.com/rotationconverter/

Comment: as soon as I used corresponding Euler angles [ x: -149.7, y: -52.0, z: 179.5 ] (also calculated with that webpage, entering -30,220,60 at "Axis with angle magnitude" input) the M matrix is OK

Comment: That is because you multiplied the matrices wrong: the first rotation must be rightmost, i.e. M = Mz × My × Mx, in your notation. I said this in my first comment, but now reviewing it, the part in parenthesis is weirdly worded even to myself. Me fail English often.

Comment: @Nominal Animal: yes, you are right. that was the problem, the order of matrix multiplication. the think is that in algorithm that I use the system coordinates is Left Handed, wiith Y axis pointing upwards(yaw rotation around Y axis), so I was a bit missconfused when I choose the order of multiplication.